# Integrate Form Flow bot in custom client

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a form flow bot using Dialogs in C#. Here is my bot code-

This is **RootDialog.cs**

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    #region Fields
    private const string SearchFileOption = "Search files";
    private const string QueryKBOption = "Query Knowledge Base";
    #endregion
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
    {
        this.ShowMenuOptions(context);
    }
    public virtual async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> activity)
    {
        try
        {
            string optionSelected = await activity;

            switch (optionSelected)
            {
                case SearchFileOption:
                    context.Call(new SearchDialog(), ChildDialogComplete);
                    break;

                case QueryKBOption:
                    context.Call(new QueryDialog(), ChildDialogComplete);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (TooManyAttemptsException ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attempts :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");

            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
    public virtual async Task ChildDialogComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> response)
    {
        this.StartOverAgain(context);
    }
    #region Prompts
    private void ShowMenuOptions(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Choice(context: context, resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync, options: new List<string>() { SearchFileOption, QueryKBOption }, prompt: "What would you like to do today?", retry: "Selected option not available. Please try again.", attempts: 3);
    }
    private void StartOverAgain(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Choice(context: context, resume: AskConfirmation, prompt: "Would you like to start over again?", retry: "Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again.", options: (IEnumerable<ConfirmationChoices>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConfirmationChoices)));
    }
    public virtual async Task AskConfirmation(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<ConfirmationChoices> Query)
    {
        var response = await Query;
        if (response == ConfirmationChoices.Yes)
        {
            this.ShowMenuOptions(context);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Thank you.");
            context.Done(this);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This is **QueryDialog.cs**

```
[Serializable]
public class QueryDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Welcome to the QnA Service!");
        this.AskQuery(context);
    }

    public virtual async Task GetQueryAnswer(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> Query)
    {
        string response = await Query;
        await context.PostAsync(QnAFunctions.GetAnswer(response));
        this.AskConfirmQuestion(context);
    }
    public virtual async Task AskConfirmation(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<ConfirmationChoices> Query)
    {
        var response = await Query;
        if (response == ConfirmationChoices.Yes)
        {
            this.AskQuery(context);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Done(this);
        }
    }

    #region Prompts
    private void AskQuery(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Text(context: context,resume: GetQueryAnswer, prompt: "Please share your query", retry: "Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again.");
    }
    private void AskConfirmQuestion(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Choice(
            context: context, resume: AskConfirmation, prompt: "Do have any other query?", retry: "Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again.", options: (IEnumerable<ConfirmationChoices>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConfirmationChoices)));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Similarly, I have prepared **SearchDialog.cs**

Here is my **MessagesController.cs**

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}

private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
    if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
    {
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == message.Recipient.Id))
        {
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
            Activity reply = message.CreateReply("Hi!, I am your service provider virtual assistant. ");
            connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
    {
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
    {
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I am trying to embed this bot in my custom chat window which is a part of MVC application.

And here is the code that I am trying for calling bot.

```
public string TalkToTheBot2(string paramMessage)
{
    DirectLineClient client = new DirectLineClient(DirectLineSecret);
    Conversation conversation = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["conversation"] as Conversation;

    string watermark = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["watermark"] as string;
    if (conversation == null)
    {
        conversation = client.Conversations.StartConversation();

    }

    Activity message = new Activity
    {
        Text = paramMessage,
        From = new ChannelAccount(),
        Type = ActivityTypes.Event
    };
    var result = client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversation.ConversationId, message).Result;
    Chat objChat = ReadBotMessagesAsync(client, conversation.ConversationId, watermark);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["conversation"] = conversation;
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["watermark"] = objChat.watermark;
    objChat.ChatMessage = paramMessage;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objChat);
}
private Chat ReadBotMessagesAsync(DirectLineClient client, string conversationId, string watermark)
{
    Chat objChat = new Chat();
    bool messageReceived = false;
    while (!messageReceived)
    {

        var activitySet = client.Conversations.GetActivitiesAsync(conversationId, watermark).Result;
        watermark = activitySet?.Watermark;
        var activities = from x in activitySet.Activities
                         where x.From.Id == botId
                         select x;
        foreach (Activity message in activities)
        {
            if (message.Text != null)
            {

                objChat.ChatResponse
                    += " "
                    + message.Text.Replace("\n\n", "<br />");
            }

            if (message.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {

                objChat.ChatResponse
                    += " "
                    + RenderImageHTML(message.Attachments[0].ContentUrl);
            }
        }
        messageReceived = true;
    }
    objChat.watermark = watermark;
    return objChat;
}
```

This code is not working. When I post `TalkToTheBot2('Hi')` for the first time, it returns me message `'Hi!, I am your service provider virtual assistant.'` which I have defined in `MessagesController`. After this if I again call `TalkToTheBot2('Hi')` it returns `null`.

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of pictures of your code

Comment: @lebelinoz I have uploaded my code.